# Dealing with duplicated data, reassign a new value

Tags: r, duplicates

It seems that when we have duplicated data, most of the time we want to remove the duplicated data.

Lets say, we do not want to exclude it, but instead assign it with a new variable.
Taking the following data as a example

```
b <- c(1:100,1:99,1:104,1:105,1:105)
```

So we see that between the values for 1-99 are repeated 5 times, the number 100 repeated 4 times, the number 101 repeated 4 times etc.....

How can one search through `b` (ideally in sequential order), find a repeated/duplicate number and then assign it a new value

Comment: can you give a desire output example? what you like to be assigned to ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you're interested in assigning one (universal) new value

```
b <- c(1:100,1:99,1:104,1:105,1:105)

b[duplicated(b)] = 888 # new value
```

The `duplicated` command helps you spot the positions of all values that are duplicates in `b`.

Comment: Great, but is there a command to assign a new value to the duplicated values?

Comment: That's what you do in my example. All duplicated values will get 888 as the new value.